# do recursive methods allow for multiple variables of the same name to be created?

Tags: java, file, recursion, directory

I have to come up with a way to recursively go through a directory and list all of the files and subdirectory files in it. I'm pretty sure I've come up with a solid way to do this, however I need a File array to temporarily hold the list of files and directories in the current directory.
My question is, once the program calls itself again, will that temporary array be rewritten to the list of files and directories in the now open directory or is some kind of new array created?

The code isn't finished, I am just including it to give an idea of what I'm working with. When the temp array is called again if a subdirectory exists will the program still have the temp array when it eventually traverses back to the first call?
if not, what could I do to fix this? I thought about creating a list, but keep running into trouble with type conversion.

```
private void enumerateDirectory(File f)
    {
        if(f.isDirectory()){                
            File[] temp = f.listFiles();

            for(int i = 0; i<temp.length; ++i){
                if(temp[i].isDirectory()){
                    enumerateDirectory(temp[i]);
                }
                else{
                    items[i].add(temp[i]);
                }
            }

        }
            else{
                 //error message to go here
            }
    }
```

Comment: The file array will not be overwritten because it will be pushed down the stack. I would do it with List for the `items` array , because its expandable and avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` that potentially might appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the method recurses, it's as if it is a completely new method call -- you never have to worry about variable names colliding because you only have access to the variables in your current method execution. For example,

```
public void a() {
    int v = 1;
    b();
}

public void b() {
    // can't access v;
}
```

The method `b()` can't access the variable `v`. It's the same case for you, except instead of `a()` calling `b()`, it's `enumerateDirectory()` calling itself.

Besides, the local variable names are thrown away when the program is compiled, and they are replaced with offsets on the stack. In this case it's a pointer to an array, so it would just be a small pointer reference in each frame.

**EDIT**:
However, the elements in `items` will be overridden, since it's not a local variable. I'm not sure if that's what you intended. Each time a method does work on `items`, the contents stay the same since it's a field in your class (I'm guessing since I don't see it in the code). That means if `a()` fills it with `null`s, then when `b()` gets there there will be `null`s in there still.

Comment: thank you, yes I realized that about my items list shortly after posting. Probably just going to add a counter of some kind in a class scope that increases every time an item is added instead of tying it to i

Answer (score 0):

When a recursive call is made, the method clones itself, making new copies of:
the code, the local variables (with their initial values),and the parameters.

In your case for the first invocation you keep all files in an array temp (provided f is directory):

```
File[] temp = f.listFiles();
```

Then you iterate over the files in temp and for every file again call method recursively passing the name of the file. Now we have a new copy of method where file passed will be parameter `f` for the method. When this copy of method is over the control will return back to the next statement after loop.

> When the temp array is called again if a subdirectory exists will the
>   program still have the temp array when it eventually traverses back to
>   the first call?
>   Yes it will be.